# Switching accounts in Google Apps Script HTML Service

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to allow users of my Google Apps Script web app to switch google accounts. I've tried sending users to the Account Chooser via a hyperlink:

```
<a href="https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://script.google.com/a/macros/[domain]/s/[site_id]/exec">Switch Accounts</a>
```

If the user chooses another account on that screen, the user returns to the web app *still* logged in under the original account.

What am I doing wrong, or is there another way of allowing users to switch accounts whilst on the web app?

Answer (score -1):

While you might be needing [Google Apps Script HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface) to serve web pages that can interact with server-side Apps Script functions for your custom user interface, you might also need [Admin SDK's Directory API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) to manage users.

As stated in the documentation,

> The Admin SDK Directory service allows you to use the Admin SDK's Directory API in Apps Script. This API gives administrators of Google Apps domains (including resellers) the ability to manage devices, groups, users, and other entities in their domains.

First, you may use [**`users: list`**](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) to list all possible users. Example, you can list users in a domain which can be sorted by first name:

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'example.com',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Then, use [**`users: get`**](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) to [retrieve a user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user).

Here's a sample code to get a user by email address and logs all of their data as a JSON string.

```
function getUser() {
  var userEmail = 'liz@example.com';
  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);
  Logger.log('User data:\n %s', JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
}
```

Furthermore, please note that there are [Directory API: Prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites) and also needs authorization as described in [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing) in using this API.

This may seem to be a bit confusing so I suggest that you please go through the given links for more information.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi Tayam. Thank you for your response and I'm very grateful for it, however, I do not believe you have answered my quite specific question. Firstly, I am already using Google Apps Script's HTML Service to serve html pages to users. The question is if a user visits that page with one Google account but wants to visit it with another Google account instead (because maybe one account has privileges that the other doesn't, e.g. a member of the domain where the script is), can I provide the user with a method of switching accounts whilst on my page?